# Django AssertionError GraphQL

Tags: python, django

I have an error on my GraphQL instance, I load the /graphql endpoint and it pops up with the below error.

```
AssertionError: You need to pass a valid Django Model in AuthorType.Meta, received "None".
```

My schema for each is as follows:

```py
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        models = models.Profile


class PostType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post


class TagType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Tag
```

I also have a Query within that schema:

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_posts = graphene.List(PostType)
    author_by_username = graphene.Field(AuthorType, username=graphene.String())
    post_by_slug = graphene.Field(PostType, slug=graphene.String())
    posts_by_author = graphene.List(PostType, username=graphene.String())
    posts_bt_tag = graphene.List(PostType, tag=graphene.String())

    def resolve_all_posts(root, info):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags").select_related("author").all()
        )

    def resolve_author_by_username(root, info, username):
        return models.Profile.objects.select_related("user").get(
            user__username=username
        )

    def resolve_post_by_slug(root, info, slug):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .get(slug=slug)
        )

    def resolve_posts_by_author(root, info, username):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(author__user__username=username)
        )

    def resolve_posts_bt_tag(root, info, tag):
        return (
            models.Post.objects.prefetch_related("tags")
            .select_related("author")
            .filter(tags__name__iexact=tag)
        )
```

Here is the model for the blog posts:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.get_username()
    
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-publish_date"]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

and for context I pulled from this tutorial whish is on the real python website
https://realpython.com/python-django-blog/

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you have a typo : model**s** = models.Profile
an aditional s, so models is None

Comment: I looked at it for well over two hours!!! I hate coding sometimes! Thank you